# Set a break-point/event listener in JS on (immediately after) Coral file uploading

Tags: javascript, aem, addeventlistener, event-listener, google-chrome-console

An image has some default aspect ratio. I upload some image to override it. Coral file-upload is used. I set it back to default. Then I try to upload the same image. But I can't cause it's saved somewhere in cache or something. No errors appear. I need to delete it from this cache to be able to upload an image repeatedly. To find this cache I need to set a break-point on file upload or listen to it.

UPDATE:
I've fixed the issue by making Coral file upload async (setting its _async property to true). This makes we are able to upload the same files repeatedly. And no checking whether such file already exists in the uploadQueue or in cache occurs.

Comment: Please show us the code that is responsible for the file upload.

Comment: @Bergi Coral.FileUpload does it. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/coral-ui/coralui3/Coral.FileUpload.html